# Bubblesorting an array of 25 elements in the best case

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

The following application/theory question has come up in my algorithms class and I have gotten conflicting answers from both my professor and TA.

> How many comparisons are needed to bubblesort an array in the (a) worst case? (b) best case?

I know that the standard bubblesort algorithm is

`for i = 0 to n - 2
   for j = n - 1 to i + 1
       if A[j - 1] > A[j]
           swap(A[j - 1], A[j])`

I have actually Googled this question and the answer to the question is actually `300` and `24` respectively. But I'm confused about the word "comparisons" here. What do we consider a comparison? Do we consider it just the `if` check itself, or the block of code that it executes if true? In the worst case, both the swap and `if` statement will execute a total of `n(n-1)/2` times. In the best case, however, the `if` statement will check for validity `n(n-1)/2` times like before, but since the array is sorted in the best case, no swaps will occur. This would mean that the number of comparisons would be the same for both the worst case and the best case, no?

My professor said that "comparison" means "comparing the two elements" but didn't explain much more than that. My TA thinks it's likely to be based on the number of executions of the `for` loops.

It has caused me to be a lot more confused though: How do we extract that bubblesort is `O(n)` in the best case from this definition of the algorithm? Obviously, in the best case no swaps will occur, but the inner loop will run for each value of `i` in the outer for loop, so the algorithm goes through the array `n(n-1)/2` times. What exactly is just `n-1` times here that gives us `O(n)`?

The answer to the original question that I found uses the optimized bubblesort algorithm which uses only 1 for loop that quits if no swaps occur. Would this be a better algorithm to use for the question? i.e.,

`bubblesort_optimized(A)
 assume we are not done sorting
 while we are not done sorting
    assume we're done sorting
    traverse the list element by element from i = 1 to n - 1.
    if A[i-1] > A[i], swap
    if a swap occurs, we are not done sorting`

In this particular case, it's incredibly evident where it all comes from. But the algorithm from lectures and our book never mentions this.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do we consider a comparison? Do we consider it just the if check itself, or the block of code that it executes if true?

Just the `if` check. However, you are correct that the number of swaps in the worst case is exactly the same.

> How do we extract that bubblesort is O(n) in the best case from this definition of the algorithm?

You are absolutely right, the implementation that you use is *not* O(n) in the best case. You need to make a small optimization to make it stop when there are no swaps in the inner loop:

```
bool done = false
while (!done)
    done = true
    for j = n - 1 to i + 1
         if A[j - 1] > A[j]
              swap(A[j - 1], A[j])
              done = false
```

This way the outer loop is going to stop as soon as there are no swaps done in the inner loop. In the best case the first iteration of the inner loop will also be the last one, producing the expected O(n) number of comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

> What do we consider a comparison?

The `if` statement is the comparison. It's the only code in that snippet that is testing anything.

> This would mean that the number of comparisons would be the same for both the worst case and the best case, no?

With that code snippet, yes.

> How do we extract that bubblesort is `O(n)` in the best case from this definition of the algorithm?

It's not, based on the previous answer.

Skipping to your last question (because it answers the remaining ones):

> The answer to the original question that I found uses the optimized bubblesort algorithm which uses only 1 for loop that quits if no swaps occur. Would this be a better algorithm to use for the question?

It's probably more complicated, depending on how it's written, but in terms of optimizing for the number of comparisons, it will be better.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that with this exact pseudocode, the number of comparisons made is always the same because the code makes the same comparisons every single time. Notice that this code doesn't do what bubble sort normally does, which is breaking out of the loop as soon as a pass is made where no swaps happen, so it actually *doesn't* run in time O(n) in the best case. This code always takes time Θ(n<sup>2</sup>). In fact, I wouldn't really call that code bubble sort for precisely that reason.

If you update the code so that you break out of the outer loop when no changes have been made to the underlying array, then you start getting more interesting patterns and behavior. That's where you get O(n) best-case runtime, 24 comparisons made in the best case, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i = 0 to n - 2
   for j = n - 1 to i + 1
       if A[j - 1] > A[j]
           swap(A[j - 1], A[j])
```

The comparison that is taking place here is the third line, as you suggested.  I think the meaningful part of this is that we are comparing two elements of A to one-another.  A[j-1] and A[j].  The specific comparison we are doing here is a greater than comparison. (Is X1 > X2?) We are looking at two elements and determining a relationship between them.

> I have actually Googled this question and the answer to the question is actually 300 and 24 respectively.

This is going to be true for a specific value of n, not for all cases of n.  n is the number of elements you have in the array, and when we talk about time complexities, they are usually in reference to the size of the set we are looking at.